# Http cache with https protocol

Tags: http, caching, https, http-headers

I've set up cache for my rails application. I use conditional cache with ETag and Last-Modified headers for few pages and browser cache with Cache-Control header for few other pages. It is working ok.

But, after we set up ssl for our server, browser dont want to get pages from cache. I see the same headers for http and https protocols, but for http protocol in Chrome Developer tools in network panel I see status code 200 (from cache) for cached pages, but 200 OK for these pages with https protocol. Here is list of request headers:

```
Accept:text/html, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie: ...
Referer: ...
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1712.3 Safari/537.36
X-PJAX:true
X-PJAX-Container:#pjax-container
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
```

And response headers:

```
Cache-Control:max-age=600, public
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 20 Nov 2013 10:38:07 GMT
Last-Modified:Wed, 20 Nov 2013 08:41:45 GMT
Server:nginx/1.1.19
Set-Cookie: ...
Status:200 OK
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-Request-Id:71c60772-bc9f-4080-98ad-0c75c589043a
X-Runtime:0.047251
X-UA-Compatible:chrome=1
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

For conditional cache I have similar problem. Server set Last-Modified header, but for next request browser doesn't send 'If-Modified-Since' header, because of it conditional cache doesn't work. And it is working ok for http protocol. Here is list of request headers:

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie: ...
Referer: ...
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1712.3 Safari/537.36
X-CSRF-Token: ...
```

And response headers:

```
Cache-Control:max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 20 Nov 2013 10:41:33 GMT
Last-Modified:Wed, 20 Nov 2013 10:20:44 GMT
Server:nginx/1.1.19
Set-Cookie: ...
Status:200 OK
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-Request-Id:35054727-1b1a-497d-a830-6499ed9cad7a
X-Runtime:0.012432
X-UA-Compatible:chrome=1
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

Browser caches css and js files from this server, but not rendered pages. Why browser dont cache pages for https protocol? How I can make browser cache these pages?